# Android. issue with logcat with shell and from app

Tags: android, shell

if i do with adb shell:

```
logcat -d -v time InCall:I *:s
```

i get :
[image]

but in android app:

```
 public static StringBuilder getLog() {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String[] command = new String[] { "logcat", "-d", "-v", "time", "InCall:I *:s" };

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //if (line.contains(processId)) {
                    builder.append(line);
                    //Code here
                    Log.e(TAG, line);
                //}
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLog failed", ex);
        }

        return builder;
    }
```

i get only:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
```

Why? Hot to get logs like with adb shell?

Comment: because you can't read other app log from your app starting from API 16(or 17) without `android.permission.READ_LOGS` which cannot be granted without root

Comment: @Selvin do you need that permission to read logs from your own app? Or is that permission only for reading logs of other apps?